# How to test form submission in React with Jest and Enzyme? Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm writing a test to check if the error Notification component displays if the login form is submitted with no data.

```
describe('User signin', () => {
    it('should fail if no credentials are provided', () => {
        const loginComponent = shallow(<Login />);
        expect(loginComponent.find('.form-login').length).toBe(1);
        loginComponent.find('.form-login').simulate('submit');
        expect(loginComponent.find(Notification).length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

It looks like the `.simulate` is working as the test reaches my `handleSubmit` function, however I am running into this error in the test:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

[image]

#### The handleSubmit function

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // <-- problem here
    const user = this.state.username;
    const pass = this.state.password;
    const gotoDashboard = () => this.props.history.push('/dashboard');

    const postLogin = (user, pass) => {
        api.userLogin(user, pass)
```

My test will past if I remove the `e.preventDefault();` line, however I need that line in there to prevent the default form submission event.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Figured it out quickly... I just needed to create a fakeEvent with a fake preventDefault function and pass it along:

```
describe('User signin', () => {
    it('should fail if no credentials are provided', () => {
        const fakeEvent = { preventDefault: () => console.log('preventDefault') };
        const loginComponent = shallow(<Login />);
        expect(loginComponent.find('.form-login').length).toBe(1);
        loginComponent.find('.form-login').simulate('submit', fakeEvent);
        expect(loginComponent.find(Notification).length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Would this `loginComponent.find('.form-login').dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));` work too?

Comment: Is the default still prevented, or will the test cause a redirect and reload?

Comment: How does one get the values from the form node?